# .dic line format definition

Tags: dictionary, formatting, sublimetext2, aspell, affix

I am currently investigating the most appropriate dictionary to use in an application I am building.

Inspecting the dictionaries which are bundled with Sublime Text 2, the file format is as you would expect - a list of alphabetically ordered words. However, alot of those words have additional information appended to them. Take this snippet as an example:

```
abaft
abbreviation/M
abdicate/DNGSn
Abelard/M
abider/M
Abidjan
ablaze
abloom
aboveground
abrader/M
Abram/M
abreaction/MS
abrogator/MS
abscond/DRSG
absinthe/MS
absoluteness/S
absorbency/SM
abstract/ShTVDPiGY
absurdness/S
```

A fruitless Google search has not shed any light on what the letters after the slash (/) mean.

Maybe they hint at the sex of the word, but that is only a guess and I'd prefer to read a formal explanation of their meaning.

Has anybody come across these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letters following the slash are called affixes.  These encodings can be prefixes or suffixes that may be applied to the root word.

See [this blog post](http://typethinker.blogspot.com/2008/02/fun-with-aspell-word-lists.html) for a nice explanation and examples of what these affixes can be used for.

[Another place to look](http://aspell.net/man-html/) is the `aspell` manual.

Answer (score 8):

***TLDR***: each letter in the `.dic` file following the slash is a name of a rule in the `.aff` file.

https://superuser.com/a/633869/367530

> Each rule is in the .aff file for that language. The rules come in two
>   flavors: SFX for suffixes, and PFX for prefixes. Each line begins with
>   PFX/SFX and then the rule letter identifier (the ones that follow the
>   word in the dictionary file:
>
> `PFX [rule_letter_identifier] [combineable_flag]
>   [number_of_rule_lines_that_follow]`
>
> You can normally ignore the combinable flag, it is Y or N depending on
>   whether it can be combined with other rules. Then there are some
>   number of lines (indicated by the ) that list different possibilities
>   for how this rule applies in different situations. It looks like this:
>
> `PFX [rule_letter_identifier] [number_of_letters_to_delete]
>   [what_to_add] [when_to_add_it]`
>
> For example:
>
> - `SFX B Y 3`
> - `SFX B 0 able [^aeiou]`
> - `SFX B 0 able ee`
> - `SFX B e able [^aeiou]e`
>
> If `B` is one of the letters following a word, i.e. `someword/B`, then this is one of the
>   rules that can apply. There are three possibilities that can happen
>   (because there are three lines). Only one will apply:
>
> - `able` is added to the end when the end of the word is **not** (indicated by `^`) one of the letters in the set (indicated by `[ ]`) of letters `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, and `u`. For example, question → questionable
> - able is added to the end when the end of the word is `ee`. For example, agree → agreeable.
> - able is added to the end when the end of the word is not a vowel (`[^aeiou]`) followed by an `e`. The letter `e` is stripped (the column before able). For example, excite → excitable.
>
> PFX rules are the same, but apply at the beginning of the word instead
>   for prefixes.